# Add style programmatically to an svg before it's rendered by React?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, reactjs

I'm able to render my svg in react as

```
 render () {
     return (
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="./src/img/test.svg" ref="svg">
        </object>
     )
 }
```

I want a user to be able to change the fill by selecting a color, which is passed in as a prop. How can I change the style of the svg before I return it in render?

I've also investigated changing it in componentDidUpdate() but I think it's against the general React design pattern to manipulate the DOM there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Convert the SVG to a [data URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151014/convert-file-type-to-data-uri-react-dropzone?rq=1)
- Update the fill color by replacing the data URI
- Render it after the state change is complete

**References**

- [Some inline SVGs not rendering in IE 11 · Issue #7358 · facebook/react](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7358)
- [Escaping  tag content · Issue #3496 · facebook/react](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3496)