# Convert File type to Data URI - React-Dropzone

Tags: reactjs, multipartform-data, dropzone.js

I am having trouble integrating [React-dropzone](https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone) with [FeathersJS Upload](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/file-uploading.html)

I have successfully implemented the RESTful upload when you POST a datauri to my Upload endpoint. `{ uri: data:image/gif;base64,........}`

My issue is when selecting a file in react-dropzone and submitting the form, I am seeing a `File` type... It seem's I need to somehow convert that to a data URI.

This should be handled by Dauria... But I think my issue is in my POST request, not having the `file` property set with the correct file format. Should I be converting the `File` to `FormData`?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it from File object:

[image]

Using Image and FileReader allows you to get width, height and base64 data:

```js
onDrop = (acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) => {
  const file = acceptedFiles.find(f => f)
  const i = new Image()

  i.onload = () => {
    let reader = new FileReader()
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    reader.onload = () => {
      console.log({
        src: file.preview,
        width: i.width,
        height: i.height,
        data: reader.result
      })
    }
  }
  
  i.src = file.preview
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I assume I would need to use a Promise to resolve after the onload triggers in order to deal with this in redux.

Comment: can't tell, I'm using mobx, so after I get the trigger I just update the state. In vanilla React, you could do it with setState().